# ffmpeg avectorscope scale values not working

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using media filters in ffmpeg to create a visual representation of an audio channel like this:

**Command:**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]avectorscope=s=1920x1080:scale=lin,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a avectorscope.mp4
```

According to the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#avectorscope) the available values for `scale` are `lin`, `sqrt`, `cbrt` or `log` but none of these seem to work in my case. Am I using the scale function right? If not, what is the correct way?

**Log:**

```
Option 'scale' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000007eaf40] Error initializing filter 'avectorscope' with args 's=1920x1080:scale=lin'
Error initializing complex filters.
Option not found
```

---

*I am using ffmpeg static version 3.1.5*

Comment: That option was added in Aug 2016. Your build looks to be older than that.

Comment: You're using a release version. They are essentially frozen at the time the minor version was released (3.1, in your case). You should use a newer nightly/snapshot version.

Comment: In the future, please always include the full, uncut command line output, which will help diagnose issues faster. (@Mulvya, would you post an answer below?)

Comment: @slhck Done. Is there a way to define commonly shared links on SE sites, so they can be specified by simply typing `[keyword]` ?

Comment: @Mulvya There is the handy [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) userscript, and [there are a few `[shortcuts]`](https://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) that can be used within comments.

Comment: @slhck Thanks. Found [Auto-Link](http://stackapps.com/questions/4773/auto-link-add-links-based-on-personal-keywords), which seems closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a release version. They are essentially frozen at the time the minor version was released (3.1, in your case). The scale option for avectorscope filter  was added in Aug 2016, so it won't be included in your build.

You should use a newer nightly/snapshot version. Get them for Windows from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/